# Javascript: Buttons disabled after reloading DIV

Tags: javascript, html

I have got a form with two tabs, on both tabs you can edit data and submit your changes which is working already.
Now I want the tab where you made changes to get reloaded after you changed something (e.g. a picture URL and the thumbnail should get refreshed) to see the changes.

I have this code for the second tab

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').click(function(){
        var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
        if(clickBtnValue == 'Save') {
            var ajaxurl = 'ajax.php',
                data = $('form').serialize();
            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
                if(response == '')
                {
                    alert("Successfully saved");
                    location.href="catalog.php";
                }
                else               alert(response);
            });
        }
        else if(clickBtnValue == 'Save & Continue Edit')
        {
            var ajaxurl = 'ajax.php',
                data = $('form').serialize();
            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
                if(response == '') alert("Successfully saved");
                else               alert(response);
            });
        }
        else if(clickBtnValue == 'Add new Item')
        {
            var ajaxurl = 'ajax.php',
                data = $('#itemform').serialize();
            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
                if(response == '')
                {
                    alert("Successfully added new Item");
                    location.href="catalog.php";
                }
                else               alert(response);
            });
        }
        else if(clickBtnValue == 'Save Images')
        {
            var ajaxurl = 'saveimages.php',
                data = $('#imageform').serialize();
            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
                if(response == '')
                {
                    alert("Successfully saved");
                    $("#tab_images").load(location.href+" #tab_images>*","");
                }
                else               alert(response);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Everything is working until now, the data get saved and the DIV reloads, but now whenever I try to press a button nothing happens, even on the first tab.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
My Tab Code: http://i.epvpimg.com/9SaKb.png
Can't post it here since it is too long so I had to make a screenshot.

Comment: I don't think we have enough code (HTML, especially), to be able to help you.

Comment: Added it to main post.

Comment: you could have used http://jsfiddle.net instead of making a screenshot. there is also javascript missing, especially where clickBtnValue comes from and when the stated code is executed and how it is hooked to the buttons.

Comment: You should have posted the code in your post, it is not that long. What is `clickBtnValue`?

Comment: Edited the post again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the buttons you try to click are inside the div what you are reloading. When the content of that div is replaces, all the elements you fetched with ajax are considered as new - that also means that the click handlers you had previously on those buttons are also lost - hence they don't react the same way :D

try binding the event not on the button itself but an element outside the div that is being replaced

```
$("parent_selector_outside_ajax_div").on("click", ".btn", function() {
   //your button function
});
```

read move about event delegation with jQuery at http://api.jquery.com/on/

As your external js library binds it's own buttons I suggest moving those buttons outside the div you are trying to update (which shouln't be a big problem as you are trying to update only for the sake of them image previews? :D).

The other alternative (which I wouln't do) would be to rebind those buttons again after the ajax has reloaded by calling whatever function the library offers to initialize itself. *If your application is long lived, you also should, before replacing the old content with a new one, remove all the event handlers from the current content, to avoid possible memory leaks in some browsers (not sure what is your target audience).*

Comment: EDIT: Looks like this only worked for one button, two other buttons to upload images (external .js file) do not work then.

Comment: the principle remains the same :D could you make a jsFiddle example  with your html, js and those external files are included so I could have a closer look at how the other buttons are affected? :D

Comment: I don't know how to use jsFiddle, but the two other buttons are also convered by the same parent div as the first button. Here is the other script: http://pastebin.com/nwMP7EnP

Comment: I can't move the buttons outside the div since then they would not be on the tab page. And rebinding the buttons did not work too.

Comment: can't help you much further if you don't give me more code to work with :D please take a look at jsfiddle.net, paste your relevant html in there and any javascript bits you have - your current example in your question does not include any refrence to that external library or how it gets initialized

Comment: The external js gets initialized with jQuery(document).ready(function()

Comment: sorry but that's not informative enough.. is EcommerceProductsEdit.init() called anywhere or some other function on that library to fire it up? it is too difficult to "guess" a solution without seeing more code :P